# SharpApp and Office JS API

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack, office-js

I am working with SharpApp. I have created the SharpApp using the Parcel template. Now I am trying to integrate/develop the Excel Web Add-In using Office JS API. But when I run the application I got this error in the browser dev tool console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Office is not defined
    at Object.parcelRequire.QCba.tslib (index.ts:23)
    at f (client.0faf50ad.js:1)
    at parcelRequire.CvJj (client.0faf50ad.js:1)
    at client.0faf50ad.js:1
```

I have this code in the index.ts

```
Office.initialize = () => {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('office ready');
    });
};
```

Any solution to resolve this issue. I have work with office js api using Angular project template and we install the node js packages using npm, I tried to install them here but no difference.

Regards,
Jamil

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the Officejs package in the context of an addin, e.g. using the [Yeoman generator for office](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office).

But there are other libraries like [ews-javascript-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ews-javascript-api) which may suit your needs.

Comment: Could that be used as the replacement of Office JS API?

Comment: No, its not a replacement but you can use it to get/send emails/attachments/contacts/... . What do you need to achieve ?

Comment: We are building the Excel Task Pane Add-In, which read/write an excel sheet and performs different operations that are available int he Office JS API for Excel.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SharpApp. Did you install the office package ? `npm install @microsoft/office-js --save`

Comment: Yes, I did, but the result is the same.

Comment: The error is not at compilation time. It's a runtime error.

Comment: Just to clarify, you did sideload the addin into excel ?

Comment: Yes I do, and I got this
https://www.screencast.com/t/Wcjg7CqC6woD

Comment: Do you load `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>` in your `taskpane.html` ?

Comment: Yes, I already did that. Here is the layout.html file.
https://www.screencast.com/t/ZvQhBbqj

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. I just moved the office.js script statement into the header section.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)